# picocli : List<> Option, used in @ArgGroup, duplicated in short usage string

Tags: picocli

When a `List<>` option is used in an `@ArgGroup`, it is duplicated in the short usage help. Consider the following code:

```java
import picocli.CommandLine;
import picocli.CommandLine.*;
import picocli.CommandLine.Model.CommandSpec;

@Command(name = "MyApp")
public class App implements Runnable {

    @ArgGroup(exclusive=true) // or false
    MyGroup myGroup;

    static class MyGroup {
        @Option(names="-A", paramLabel="N", split=",") List<Long> A;
    }

    @Spec CommandSpec spec;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("OK: %s%n", spec.commandLine().getParseResult().originalArgs());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CommandLine(new App()).execute("-h");
    }
}
```

Shows the following output

```
Usage: MyApp [[-A=N[,N...]] [-A=N[,N...]]...]
```

I was expecting the output

```
Usage: MyApp [-A=N[,N...]]
```

`@ArgGroup` is needed in the code for other reasons, it may seem futile in this toy example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have found a bug in picocli.
Would you mind raising this on the picocli [issue tracker](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues)?

---

Update:

## The short story

This was a bug. In the next version of picocli, the expected synopsis can be achieved by setting the argument group to `exclusive = false`.

## The long story

This synopsis stuff can get quite complex... Let's break it down.

#### Option Synopsis

Before we go into argument groups, let's first look at simple options. Picocli shows a different synopsis for required and non-required options, and for single-value and multi-value options.

The below table illustrates. Note especially the notation for **required multi-value options**. Such options must be specified *at least once, but possibly multiple times*, and the synopsis reflects this:

```
               Required         Non-Required
               ---------        ------------
Single value   -x=N             [-x=N]
Multi-value    -x=N [-x=N]...   [-x=N]...
```

#### Argument Group Synopsis

Now, let's look at groups.  In `exclusive` groups (the default), all arguments are **automatically made `required`**. (There is some history behind this, but basically anything else did not make sense.) In non-exclusive groups, options can be required or optional.

Groups have a `multiplicity`. The default is `multiplicity = "0..1"` meaning the group is optional, and this is shown in the synopsis by surrounding the group with `[` and `]` square brackets.

Now, let's put these together. The table below shows the synopsis for groups with two options, `-x` and `-y`:

```
               Exclusive Group                     Non-Exclusive Group
               ---------------------------------   -------------------
Single value   [-x=N  | -y=M]                      [[-x=N] [-y=M]]
Multi-value    [-x=N [-x=N]... | -y=M [-y=M]...]   [[-x=N]... [-y=M]...]
```

#### Split Regex Synopsis

The final element: when the option accepts a `split=","` regex, the `N` parameter label becomes `N[,N...]` in the synopsis.

#### Problem: synopsis too long

When I execute your example with picocli 4.3.2, I get the following synopsis:

```
Usage: MyApp [[-A=N[,N...]] [-A=N[,N...]]...]
```

This is incorrect, and does not follow the specifications above.

With picocli 4.3.3-SNAPSHOT, I get the correct synopsis:

```
Usage: MyApp [-A=N[,N...] [-A=N[,N...]]...]
```

Given the above, we now know why: this is the synopsis for a multi-value option on an exclusive group. The option became a `required` option because the group is exclusive.

#### Getting a shorter synopsis

With picocli 4.3.3, one idea is to make the group non-exclusive (after all, with only one option, exclusive or non-exclusive does not matter). The program is almost unchanged (`exclusive = false` instead of `true`):

```java
@Command(name = "MyApp")
public class App implements Runnable {

    @ArgGroup(exclusive = false) // was:  exclusive=true
    MyGroup myGroup;

    static class MyGroup {
        @Option(names="-A", paramLabel="N", split=",")
        List<Long> A;
    }
    // ...
}
```

The synopsis of the usage help message now looks like this:

```
Usage: MyApp [[-A=N[,N...]]...]
```

I hope this explains things.

Comment: Ok, I have it [here](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/1065).

Comment: Thanks for following up in so much detail on this. I can follow the output better now.

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, consider accepting it (and perhaps upvoting it).